# Android - Play Store - API total count installs

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I did a large search but couldn't find anything concrete (I could be wrong).

I have an app in production on the Google Play Store and I would like to have the total of the installations by simply calling an API.
As far as you know, is there an API that gives me back the total installs of a specific app?

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Google play has provided the Play Install Referrer library which is very simple to use.

Inside `build.gradle` add this line in dependencies

`implementation "com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2"`

Then inside your `MainActivity` or some where else add this

`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var referrerClient: InstallReferrerClient
  
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        // others initializations

        trackReferrer()
    }


    fun trackReferrer() {
        referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
        referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

            override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
                when (responseCode) {
                    InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                        // Connection established.

                        val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
                        val referrerUrl: String = response.installReferrer
                        val referrerClickTime: Long = response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
                        val appInstallTime: Long = response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
                        val instantExperienceLaunched: Boolean = response.googlePlayInstantParam

                        // do what you want to do with referral data here
                    }
                    InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                        // API not available on the current Play Store app.
                    }
                    InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        // Connection couldn't be established.
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [read the doc here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
However, I was looking for an API that would return the total number of installations of my app.
In the way you propose I should save the data on my server, correct?

Comment: Yep, to my knowledge there is no such API.